# Equivalent settings for pdfdisplaydoctitle and pdflang in ConTeXt?

Tags: pdftex, context

I'm trying to generate accessible PDFs which require the Primary Language of the PDF (the PDF language identifier - RFC 3066) to be set and that the document is displaying the title instead of the filename when opened.

Right now, using the \mainlanguage or \language commands doesn't set the PDF language identifier and setting title in \setupinteraction still displays the filename.

With LaTeX, the hyperref package can be used to do this by setting pdfdisplaydoctitle and pdflang.

Is there a way to do the same in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 3):

The title of the document can be set via `\setupinteraction`.  Keep in mind that there is no way to force the viewer to display that title.  Some viewers choose to show you the filename no matter what.

I took a peek at the `hyperref` source to find out how `pdflang` and `pdfdisplaydoctitle` are handled and found that they are placed in `\pdfcatalog`.  ConTeXt completely abstracts away the concepts of the pdfcatalog into high-level interfaces.  Unfortunately, `pdflang` and `pdfdisplaydoctitle` are not accessible from the high level, so we have to go all the way down to Lua to inject stuff into the pdfcatalog.  I found out about this in the [`pdf-ua.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/test/mkiv/pdf-ua.mkiv) test file.

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=start,
   title={Foobar}]

\setupbackend
  [level=0] % compresslevel=0, so I can inspect the PDF

\startluacode
    lpdf.addtocatalog("Lang",lpdf.string("\currentmainlanguage"))
    lpdf.addtocatalog("ViewerPreferences",lpdf.dictionary{DisplayDocTitle = true})
\stopluacode

\starttext

Hello World

\stoptext
```

```
$ grep --text Catalog test.pdf
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 11 0 R /Lang (en) /Metadata 12 0 R /PageLabels << /Nums [ 0 << /S /D /St 1 >> ] >> /PageMode /UseNone /Version /1.7 /ViewerPreferences << /DisplayDocTitle true >>>>
```

Comment: `/Lang` might actually be set automatically by ConTeXt when you're producing PDF/X or PDF/A.